# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: SIGSEGV, Problematic frame: custom code

Tags: java, segmentation-fault, jvm, fatal-error

We are moving our J2EE application from WebSphere to JBoss.

In first smoke tests we had a couple of time a JVM crash, but we aren't able to find the path to reproduce the problem yet.

The JVM crash causes the following:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fff8df86788, pid=3555039, tid=821817
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (11.0.12+7) (build 11.0.12+7-LTS)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (11.0.12+7-LTS, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, linux-ppc64le)
# Problematic frame:
# J 210874 c2 custom.package.ClientEnvironmentServiceImpl.isMobileDevice(Ljava/lang/String;Ljavax/servlet/http/Cookie;)Ljava/lang/Boolean; (64 bytes) @ 0x00007fff8df86788 [0x00007fff8df85e80+0x0000000000000908]
```

This the command line and arguments to start the server

```
Command Line: -D[Standalone] -Xlog:gc*:file=/logs/jboss/cert/Product/gc.log:time,uptimemillis:filecount=5,filesize=3M -Xms9216m -Xmx12288m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djboss.as.management.blocking.timeout=10800 -Djorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dgw.server.mode=prod -Dgw.cc.env=FORM -Dgw.cc.serverid=FORM1NSSA -Duser.region=US --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/logs/jboss/cert/Product/server.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:/product/jboss-servers/cert/Product/configuration/logging.properties -agentpath:/product/dynatrace/agent/bin/1.265.152.20230519-165227/linux-ppcle-64/liboneagentloader.so=loglevelcon=none,datastorage=/dynatrace/runtime,logdir=/dynatrace/logs /product/jboss-eap/cert/jboss-modules.jar -mp /product/jboss-eap/cert/modules org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=/product/jboss-eap/cert -Djboss.server.base.dir=/product/jboss-servers/cert/Product -Djboss.server.base.dir=/product/jboss-servers/cert/Product -Djboss.server.config.dir=/product/jboss-servers/cert/Product/configuration -Djboss.server.data.dir=/product/jboss-servers/cert/Product/data -Djboss.server.log.dir=/product/jboss-servers/cert/Product/logs -Djboss.server.temp.dir=/product/jboss-servers/cert/Product/tmp -Djboss.server.deploy.dir=/product/jboss-servers/cert/Product/deployments --server-config=standalone-full.xml -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100
```

Those information about underlying components:

```
Host: POWER9 (architected), altivec supported, 40 cores, 22G, Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.5 (Ootpa)
```

This is the thread/upper part of stacktrace involved

```
Current thread (0x0000010064c4e800):  JavaThread "webcontainer-worker task-68" [_thread_in_Java, id=821817, stack(0x00007fff197a0000,0x00007fff199a0000)]

Stack: [0x00007fff197a0000,0x00007fff199a0000],  sp=0x00007fff19999f50,  free space=2023k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, A=aot compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
J 210874 c2
custom.package.ClientEnvironmentServiceImpl.isMobileDevice(Ljava/lang/String;Ljavax/servlet/http/Cookie;)Ljava/lang/Boolean; (64 bytes) @ 0x00007fff8df86788 [0x00007fff8df85e80+0x0000000000000908]
j custom.package.ClientEnvironmentServiceImpl.isMobileDevice(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;)Ljava/lang/Boolean;+16
j  custom.package.DeviceDetectionUtil.isMobile()Z+7
j  pcfc.expressions.FNOLWizard_BasicInfoScreen_01autoExpressions$FNOLWizard_BasicInfoScreenExpressionsImpl.visible_152()Ljava/lang/Boolean;+4
jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2744.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+36
J 201421 c2
```

This the code involved

```
`private String resolveCookieName()
{
String customName = getCustomCookieName();
if (null != customName) {
return customName;
}
return ClientEnvironmentConstants.COOKIE_DEVICE;
}`
```

What we see, in both occurrences, is that the "problematic frame" is the same, and it's a custom code.
How could we use this information to investigate or reproduce the problem?

We tried to reproduce the navigation in the application that caused the problem 2 times, without any problem. In the previous application server (with different JVM) we have never seen this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should not use the one line format for an error log. Please use the multi line [code format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for code, errors and logs.

Comment: Are there more lines to the error? Share the custom code too. It could be a Java bug also. Did you change the JDK version too? And what Java arguments are you using to launch the server?

Comment: Thanks aled, added further info to description

Comment: The error message mentioned ClientEnvironmentServiceImpl.isMobileDevice(). You are showing a different method.

Comment: Are those all the lines of the error? I don't see a thread or the rest of the stacktrace.

Comment: The error message has "c2", which suggests that the c2/server compiler is at fault. Try running with the `-client` option added to the command line.

Comment: aled, added thread and upper part of stacktrace. Tks

Comment: Thanks boneill. What the -client option is supposed to do? We experienced the problem and we aren't able to reproduce, so we would like to investigate the problem on the base of the evidence collected or find a way to reproduce it.

Comment: @lorenzo c1 is the "client" compiler, and c2 is the "server" compiler. Nowadays tiered compilation is used, and so both c1 and c2 are used. You can explicitly choose one over the other, to see if it helps work around the problem. I think in the end, you'll need a newer JVM (which hopefully has a fix) or you need to file a Java bug report. https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/whitepaper.html